# Raspberry Pi Debian 11 looking how to connect to SQL Server through python

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, odbc, pyodbc, sql-server-express

I have tried multiple ways to create a connection but have been unsuccessful. I have attempted to install unixobdc. I get it downloaded but I cannot seem to get a driver... I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 running Linux Debian 11 ARM.

For SQL I am using SQLEXPRESS on a 2022 MS Server

This is my connection string:
import pyodbc

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=myservername\SQLEXPRESS'
                      'Database=mydatabasename;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

**The error message I receive:**

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
```

pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

I have tried editing my odbcinst file for the driver and did still did not work.

I am not sure what else I should try doing. I have even tried pointing my Driver to the name of the ini that I changed it to, still with no luck.

For Example

GNU nano 5.4                      /etc/obdc.ini

```
[Name Here]
Description = Description
Driver = /etc/odbcinst.ini
Database = Databasename
Servername = ServerName
UID = Username
PWD = Password
```

This us the error I receive:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Name Here};'
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Name Here' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

---

**UPDATE 06/26/23**

I still have not had any luck fully getting this implemented. Although I am running into a different error code with trying SQLServerport.

**I have done the following:**

edited the **obdcinst.ini** to this:

```
'[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
 Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
 Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql- 
 17.4.so.1.1
 UsageCount=1'
```

**OBDC.ini**

```
'[MSSQLServerDatabase]
  Driver      = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
  Description = Connect to my SQL Server instance
  Trace       = No
  Server      = *Servername*\SQLEXPRESS'
```

**python code:**

```
'# test data
server_name = "*Servername*\SQLEXPRESS"
instance_name = "SQLEXPRESS"

try:
  result = r"Instance {0}\{1} is listening on port 
  {2}.".format(
    server_name,
    instance_name,
    sqlserverport.lookup(server_name, instance_name),
    )
except sqlserverport.BrowserError as err:
    result = err.message
except sqlserverport.NoTcpError as err:
    result = err.message

print(result)'
```

****with this I am getting the following error** :**

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/kshaw/Test.py", line 59, in <module>
 sqlserverport.lookup(server_name, instance_name),
 File "/home/kshaw/.local/lib/python3.9/site- 
 packages/sqlserverport/sqlserverport.py", line 60, in 
 lookup
 sock.sendto(udp_message, (server, udp_port))
 socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'
```

I am not sure what else I may have been missing, any help would be greatly appreciated and I truly appreciate the help this far!

---

**UPDATE 6/27/23**

After slightly rewriting my code I was able I was able to get it partially working.

```
'# Try to connect to SQL Server
 server_name = "xxx.xx.xx.xx"
 instance_name = "SQLEXPRESS"

 try:
    result = r"Instance {0}\{1} is listening on port 
    {2}.".format(
    server_name,
    instance_name,
    sqlserverport.lookup(server_name, instance_name),
    )
    except sqlserverport.BrowserError as err:
    result = err.message
    except sqlserverport.NoTcpError as err:
    result = err.message

    print(result)'
```

**This is what prints:**

```
'Instance xxx.xx.xx.xx\SQLEXPRESS is listening on port 
 1433.'
```

However, I think do the connection string and I get an error:

**Connection String error:**

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/kshaw/test1.py", line 71, in <module>
```

pyodbc.connect('DSN=MSSQLServerDatabase;UID=myuid;PWD=mypwd')

```
'pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver 
 Manager]Can't open lib 
'/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.4.so.1.1' 
 : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")'
```

Comment: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Linux

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I have tried and still no luck, I will update the thread to show where I am stuck.

Comment: `server_name` should be *just* the server name or IP, not `servername\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: Thank you it may be fixed, I messed with the Py code a little bit more. I am not at work and I will need to wait to have it on the internet there but I think this could be a good sign, I received this error.

    'Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/kshaw/Test.py", line 59, in <module>
    sqlserverport.lookup(server_name, instance_name),
    File "/home/kshaw/.local/lib/python3.9/site- 
    packages/sqlserverport/sqlserverport.py", line 60, in lookup
    sock.sendto(udp_message, (server, udp_port))
    socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname'

Comment: IT IS SOOOOO CLOSE! Thank you.

I get this back

Instance xxx.xx.xx.xx\SQLEXPRESS is listening on port 1433.

But when I do the pyodbc.connect I get the following error:

pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.4.so.1.1' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

This is my connection code:

    'pyodbc.connect('DSN=MSSQLServerDatabase;UID=myuid;PWD=mypwd')
cursor = conn.cursor()'

Comment: Microsoft added support for ARM64 in version 18.1 of their "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server" so you'll likely need to [install that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=debian18-install%2Calpine17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline#18) instead of version 17.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that it still can't seem to find the driver. I think something wonky is going on. There is nothing on this Raspberry other than the code that I have been working on. I think I will just reset it and start from scratch so that I have a fresh environment. I tried to even locate it using /usr/libodbc*.so* with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar problem. Seems like the file odbcinst.ini does not get created. I followed this guide:
https://forums.raspberrypi.com//viewtopic.php?t=172498

and changed SQL server in my code to FreeTDS and that worked for me

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try when I go in tomorrow and let you know how it goes. I have also been keeping a running log of all the things that I have tried and will work with your solution and also try to work with the one by Gord. I hope that between these 2 I should be good to go! :) thanks again for everyone's contribution.

Comment: I wish you good luck, my next step is trying to connect my sql server and the pi. I have the feeling my firewall is blocking it.

Comment: Have you looked at adding your Pi to the AD? I have found and saved some documentation on how to do so.